# Using the Kindle ed060xd4 eink display with a raspberry pi when the kindle itself is broken

Tags: display, eink

Now, there have been a handful of posts about this. Most sadly point to kindleberry. Which from my understanding only works if the ereader itsself still works.

I have a working kindle eink display from a broken e-reader - so kindleberry isn't an option. (the ereader is in an infinite starting loop and doesn't show up on pc when plugged in)

The goal is to directly interface the display (ed060xd4). Any idea how this could be done? Do I need extra hardware? Where do I start?
[image]

[image]

Comment: your question is not Raspberry Pi specific

Answer (score 0):

Update: Did some more research and found an Arduino project that looks like it does exactly what I'm looking for: https://epdiy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is something I am working on at the moment. The epdiy system works fine. However you will need to send the framebuffer as an image to the esp32 or create a pcb that interfaces with the epaper instead of the esp32 and that drives the epaper directly from the PI pins.
However for general use epaper displays are not quite there yet. They are slow and even with a epaper monitor it is tricky to get many x apps to look any good. For a useful interface (ie fast enough to work with properly) you need to stick with simple Black or white. While this is fine once you adapt every interface it is a pain to setup.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/120844)